# Is it a bad idea to use a large static variable?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, static

I work with ASP.NET MVC 4 and I want to load a large amount of data and make it accessible in all my class.
Here is minimalist sample of my code :

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public static List<MyObject> myList = null;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
        myList = GetAllData(User.IDentity.Name); // Fill my list with 2k rows
        model.List = myList;

        return View(model);
    }


    public JsonResult GetData(int i)
    {
        return Json(myList.Where(x => x.Data == i));
    }
```

}

Everything is working with in local but I have some problems with multiple users when I puplish on the server (crash).

I think I made a mistake. I'm sure I have memory leaks with theses static datas.

How can I avoid this problem ? Should I use a singleton ?

Comment: Your code will throw an exception if `GetData` is called before Index.  Also you are fetching the entire list every time someone requests an index page, is that intentional?

Comment: Where is your data stored?  Would it not be more efficient for GetData to just get the row directly from the data source when requested?

Answer (score 1):

Controllers are stateless, so each call to an action creates a new instance of the controller, which would defeat the purpose of what you are trying to achieve.  That said the following in a better implementation of instantiating the static by doing it in the constructor:

```
public MyController()
{
    myList = GetAllData(); 
}
```

However, I advise against this as I think the issue is more a flaw in your design or a misunderstand of how state is handled in controllers - they are stateless.

Edit: adding example to address comment:
Common convention would be to do the follow:
1. Remove the static, it really gives you no gain.

Then:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();

        model.List = GetAllData(User.IDentity.Name);;

        return View(model);
    }


    public JsonResult GetData(int i)
    {
        var model = GetAllData(User.IDentity.Name).Where(x => x.Data == i).ToList();
        return Json(model);
    }
```

You don't need the static, client calls to Index and to GetData will never be executed in the same instance of the controller, a static is useless in this instance.

Comment: thanks for the explanations. How am I suppose to use the same object/data for a specific user if I'm not suppose to share a variable in my controller ?

Comment: See the example I added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But if I use static property it's because I want to avoid multiples calls of GetAllData() (too long !). That's why I want to load my object once on the first call and then use it between methods.

Comment: It will get called mutiple times regardless - As I said, an instance of the controller gets created each time a client calls an action method because the controller is stateless.  yoururl/mycontroller/index and /yoururl/mycontroller/getdata?i=1 cause the server to create seperate, new instance of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

There are many downsides to using static variables and in your scenario there is no reason to use them. Please use an instance variable and initialize it like this (for all controller actions):

```
private List<MyObject> myList;

protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    myList = GetAllData();
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
    model.List = myList;
    return View(model);
}

public JsonResult GetData(int i)
{
    return Json(myList.Where(x => x.Data == i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to say yes, because this is not really how things work. Everytime you call a controller, a new instance of it is created, and you need to get the data for each action. You can have a property inside your controller and populate it in the constructor, to reuse it in all actions, but this will still hit the database everytime you call an action.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{ 
    private readonly IDataGetter _dataGetter;

    public MyController(IDataGetter dataGetter)
    {
        _dataGetter = dataGetter;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
        myList = _dataGetter.GetAllData(User.IDentity.Name); // Fill your list with 2k rows
        model.List = myList;

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I think what you are after is that you don't want to hit the DB for everytime you need the data from **GetAllData()**.

What I would do (assuming that the data don't change to often and that you want to reuse this method in different controllers) is creating a *BaseController* and have your controller inherit from this instead of *Controller*. Add **OutputCache** to that controller action so that you don't have to hit the database each time.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600)] //cache 3600 sec
    public List<SomeDataModel> GetAllData()
    {
        return _dataGetter.GetAllData(User.Identity.Name);
    }
}
```

Then in all controller actions above where you want to access your data, you can make a call to this base method. This will keep it cached and you don't need to get it from the database everytime.

```
var allData = base.GetAllData();
```

*Note:* You should probably read about Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control before going trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a static constuctor?  It will only fill it once, and it will be ready for when it is needed.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public static List<MyObject> myList = null;
    static MyController()
    {
        myList = GetAllData(User.IDentity.Name); // Fill my list with 2k rows
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
        model.List = myList;

        return View(model);
    }

    public JsonResult GetData(int i)
    {
        return Json(myList.Where(x => x.Data == i));
    }
}
```